# Move in crontab -e editor

Tags: cron, vi, editors

I'm trying to manipulate the editor of crontab but it's really really confusing.
So I launch the creation of a new crontab with `crontab -e`
Then the default editor opens.

Now from there, it's seems to be LAGGING !!??

How do I move around in the editor ?

How do I get "--INSERT--" to show and then write my "script" and then type :wq to write and save exit ?

How can I go back to writing mode after pushing once esc or : ?

Answer (score 12):

You can pick any editor you like by setting the `$EDITOR` variable before calling `crontab -e`

e.g.

```
$ EDITOR=emacs crontab -e
```

will run `emacs` as your editor.  If you have a favourite editor then you can select that.

Many programs that call an external editor may also use this `$EDITOR` variable so you may find it useful to set it permanently in your `.profile` with

```
export EDITOR=emacs
```

Now `crontab -e` and others will automatically select this editor.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like `vi` or one of its many clones, probably `vim`.

You can use `i` to insert, `x` to delete the current character, `dd` to delete a line (and copy it to clipboard), `p` to paste below the current line, and `u` to undo the last change.

Hopefully that will be enough to let you do your change.  For more details, search for a `vi` manual, handbook, or tutorial.

Comment: And if you want to exit from vim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor/11828573#11828573

Answer (score 4):

`crontab -e` enters into default editor (`vi` editor). The simple shortcuts in `vi` editor are

- i - Insert mode (allows you to write data)

: mode

- :w -> we can save data
- :q -> quit from editor
- :q! -> force quit
- :wq -> save and quit

any time we can reset the mode of editor by using <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.
You can use `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` to edit `crontab` file by using the `nano` editor.

Answer (score 0):

The editor is vi, its very simple to play around, if you need to type anything press escape button and then i (i means insert) if you need to save it then again press escape button and then :wq

If you don not want to save and close press escape and then :q!

Comment: Did you just create an account so you could state that it’s very simple to play around in vi? That’s some quality trolling, I salute you.